# Wordpress thumbnail color overlay on hover

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colors, hover, overlay

I have this code in my wordpress site for turning the "Featured Image" into a thumbnail:

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
the_post_thumbnail();
echo '</a>';
}
?>
</div>
```

This is what the site looks like this far:
http://www.steakmob.com/porftolio/

I would like for the images to have a red overlay on the hover state. How can I achieve this? I've tried other tutorials, but I do not know how to adapt the jQuery and/or Javascript for wordpress and my specific code. Thanks!

Comment: You code is wrong. You're making portifolio-item an id, and it should be a class (you can't have more than one element with same id)

Answer (score 0):

Andre is correct. To answer your question, I would consider making the image fadeOut using jQuery, so that the background of the a tag shows and the image is hidden.

For example:

```
$(".portfolio-item a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('img').fadeOut("fast");
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('img').fadeIn("fast");
  }
);
```

You will need to make sure your a element is set to display:block, with a width and height. You may also consider using the [hover intent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment, you must use class name for portfolio-item, instead of id.

Said that, you can use this code to overlay hovered images with an red div:

```
$(function(){
    $("#portfolio-content .portfolio-item").hover(function(){
        var curElem = $(this).children(); // current image
        $('<div />').addClass('overlay')
                    .css('width',curElem.css('width'))
                    .css('height',curElem.css('height'))
                    .prependTo($(this).children('a'));
        return false;
    }, function(){
       $(this).children('a').children('.overlay').remove();
    });
});
```

Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wus7H/1/